# how to manage dynamic tables with hibernate - multi tenant database

Tags: spring, hibernate, database-design, multi-tenant

I am using hibernate 3 using spring 3.5 for a SaaS application. I am expecting upto 10-15 customers , not more. I do not want to implement separate db or schema per customer as its too complicated and costly for a small enterprise like mine. I am currently using a multi-tenant strategy which works fine for a host of small features. Here is the use case where my design fails:

For reporting feature each customer will have a different table for data (because of various reasons like legacy, source of data etc). Table structure differs and so does service/controller behaviors.

I am currently planning to create separate Controllers, Services (DAOs), etc for each customer, thus mapping each of such customer tables with a separate hibernate class. But this approach is not clean and for every new customer I add (which is not that often though), I would need to add its table, and also code a hibernate entity class mapped to the new table, which is not ideal as it needs coding. Is there a way to manage/map such dynamic tables using hibernate which gets added when a new customer is added ?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to manage/map such dynamic tables using hibernate which
>   gets added when a new customer is added ?

I don't know if this is directly supported by Hibernate.  [From the manual](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html#d5e4660), the supported multi-tenant options are:

- schema
- database
- discriminator

Discriminator is mentioned but is not supported in the current release of Hibernate (version 4.2).  That leaves schema and database.  You mentioned in your question that neither of these are currently applicable to your setup.  So unless you're willing to do some major restructuring, you'll probably need to proceed with a different approach.

**Option 1:**

If I were you, I'd write a view that presents the data from each tenant's table.  You can add the tenant ID as a column in the view.  Map the reporting class to the view with Hibernate.  When you run a query against the view, set the current tenant's ID as a query parameter.

If you go this route, you won't need to add new controllers and POJOs when you add a customer.  Just modify the view to also include the new customer's data and it should work.

**Option 2:**

Hibernate can [bind native SQL query results to entities](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch13.html#d5e3598).  You can have one entity that represents the data in any reporting table (this assumes that the separate per-customer tables have a similar structure).

In your reporting DAO, you'd fetch a SQL query from a properties file or specify [a named SQL query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e8422) based on the current tenant identifier.  Note that the named query approach will only meet your needs (no recompilation of Java classes) if you have things mapped with HBM files.  If your mapping is done with annotations, you'd need to rebuild the project to add a named query.

Answer (score 2):

Use Hibernate 4 multi-tenancy support, see the documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html). There is support for separate databases per tenant, separate schemas per tenant and partitioning of the same table per tenant.

Comment: the last option - partitioning of the same table per tenant - is not available until hibernate 5.0. Thanks anyways.